# finding children in array jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

this is my problem.

Thats my array structure

```
var komands              = ['komand'];
komands['komand']        = ['add','remove','move','moveto','search','index'];
komands['komand']['add'] = ['image','text','file','link','video'];
komands['komand']['add']['image'] = ['title'];
```

and thats my current function

```
$.each(komands, function(i, val) {
    $('#komand .komand-suggest').append('<div class="komand-suggest-item">'+val+'</div>');
});
```

i want to get one level deeper in my array each time i give my function one key from the array.
as example:
 i hit add and its suggesting 'image','text','file','link','video'; i type image its suggesting 'title'.

But i cant find a solution for going one level deeper every time i run my function.
any idea how to do this?

Thank in advance

### solved

solved it like this

i read my input field ans split it by space so i get something like this returend

komand = [add,image,title,tags,execute]

now i loop trough the array

```
$.each(komand, function(i, val) {
    komando=komando[val];
});
```

and i get to the level where i want to be. The problem with "what have you tried's" answer is that i have a dynamic command tree console.log(getChildren(kommands.kommand.add)); and that would be static

Thanks anyways, you helped me tho

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have named arrays, there are *objects* (which is what you want)

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5t4e81hj/5/

```
       var kommands = {
           'kommand': {
               'add': {
                   'image': 'title',
                       'text': undefined,
                       'file': undefined,
                       'link': undefined,
                       'video': undefined
               },
                   'remove': undefined,
                   'move': undefined
           }
       };

       function getChildren(obj) {
           var children = [];

           for (var i in obj) {
               if (typeof obj[i] !== 'undefined') {
                   children.push(obj[i]);
               }
           }

           return children;
       }

       console.log(getChildren(kommands.kommand.add));
```

Comment: thx for the anser but now quiet what im looking for. I made it like this now. i get an array with the list of typed commands returned. e.g. add image title and then i loop trough them and go one level deeper at a time

Comment: @StefanHövelmanns Okay, sorry about that. Could you let me know what you *are* look for then?

Comment: @StefanHövelmanns So are you looking for a recursive function?

Comment: look above i did it like that.